# OOP concepts in oracle 11.g

Tags: oracle, oop, oracle11g

i have a question related to Object Orienting  programming in  oracle  database(11.g),generally  i have studyed  how to create object types or how to create table from existing  object,but i am stoped on one topic,namely,suppose  that we have created following type

```
create or replace type mono.Item_type as object(
item_id     integer,
part       REF  mono.Part_type,
quantity    integer);
```

where  Part_type is already existed object type.
i know that i can create table from this  object like this:

create table  tablename of  Item_type,for instance

```
create table item_list of  Item_type
```

what what  would be different,if instead of this,we  use

```
create or replace type mono.Item_List as table of Item_type;
```

here  inspite of this,that we  use type   keyword,we  are creating  table again and what is different   between  `create table  tablename of  Item_type` and

```
create or replace type mono.Item_List as table of Item_type;?
```

Comment: It is unfortunate that the term "table" is used by Oracle instead of "array" when in the context of type declarations.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `create table tablename of Item_type`, you're creating a table in the DB.
This table is a structure that can be used to store user's data .

When you use `create or replace type mono.Item_List as table` you're defining a new **Datatype** (similar to array).
This Datatype can be used as a type of a column in a DB table or as a type of a variable in plsql code.